# Modify ASP.NET log level based on status code

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, serilog

By default asp.net logs when a request is finished, for example:

> Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://some/api/url application/json 183 - 500 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 375.0153ms

Ideally, I would like for these logs to be logged as an error rather than information when the status code is greater than 399.  Is there a way to configure this without having to write a custom logger / logging provider?

Tried using serilog with a custom sink.  While this could work, I don't like the idea of having a sink around a sink just to change a log level property.  Serilog enrichers also don't work for this since log level is read only.

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible. You can follow this issue for updates: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36841